# Splitting string data in order to apply load_qa_chain

Tags: langchain

```
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=80) 
chunks = text_splitter.split_text(PolicyScheduleRaw) 

for chunk in chunks:
    print(chunk)
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
```

So I have the code above that splits the string PolicyScheduleRaw into chunks. This above step completes successfully. However, when I then proceed to execute the below code, I get the error message: `'str' object has no attribute 'page_content'`

```
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key="SECRET")
question = "Are my Bosch power tools covered?"
chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type='stuff')

result = chain.run(input_documents=chunks, model='gpt-3.5-turbo-1106',question=question)
```

If I change `split_text` to `create_documents` in the first code block (I read somewhere that this could be the cause), then the chunk size of 1,000 no longer applies and for some reason the text is split per each character.

How can I fix this?